# My laptop DGPU died and I'm unable to install Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, freeze, gpu, wayland

My laptop dGPU card died, now it works on iGPU. Windows working good, in Device Manager it shows card with exclamation mark, but when I'm trying to install ubuntu with flash drive it freeze while on booting and shows only Ubuntu logo. Last time I managed to install it from safe mode but I was able to use only Wayland, When I was trying to switch to Xorg it got freezed.

Any ideas How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Blacklist your dGPU in GRUB, or replace it. What's the make and model?

Comment: It's samsung ativ book 8 NP880Z5E-X01SE and GPU is soldered on the motherboard. 

How can I blacklist dGPU while I'm unable to even install ubuntu?